# Retrieve emebedded or component using Hibernate Criteria api

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have this class mapped as a entity, lets call it Person. Person has an embedded/component relation to Address. I am having trouble using a Criteria that would return Address objects. 
I have tried this:

```
Criteria.createCriteria(Address.class)
```

Which does not work. I guess I need to go through the entity but then I would need some kind of projection?

```
Criteria.createCriteria(Person.class).<<what goes here???>>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Component's lifetime is controlled by its owner; they are NOT considered associations. You therefore cannot retrieve component by itself from a query. You can, however, use it in criteria.

Assuming your "Address" class is mapped as "address" within "Person", you could do something like:

```
Criteria.createCriteria(Person.class)
 .add(Restrictions.eq("address.street", street));
```

Comment: Ok, but how come I can do a HQL and retrieve the Address directly? Why does not the same apply for queries?

Comment: Because HQL has capabilities that Criteria API does not. Now, if you really want to return your Address alone at any cost, you can create a projection list for Person-based criteria that would contain every property of Address (and nothing else) and apply `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` to a result. But this is a lot of headache and nothing to show for it; I'd select full Person instead and extract Address (if that's what you need) in java code. Or go with HQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is how one can retrieve or refer the property of embedded object in hibernate.

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                Parent.class,"parent");
criteria.createAlias("embeddedObjectFieldName", "parent.embeddedObjectFieldName");

criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("parent.propertyOne"))
                .add(Projections.max("embeddedObjectFieldName.embeddedobjectproperty")));
```

Hope above clarifies